# Receiving value from another column in SpecFlow Feature file with Examples

Tags: c#, cucumber, specflow, gherkin

I'm writing BDD Tests with SpecFlow in c#. I'm trying to, in a beautiful way, take the value of one of the columns and use it as input to another column.
Code:

```
Examples:
| volume    | error |
|  0        | Volume must be greater than 0 but is <volume> |
```

I'd like `<volume>` to take the value 0 in this case. Is this possible? This is obviously not working at the moment.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not possible. One could argue that the connection between the two volume values would be more noticeable, easier to understand, but if you actually substitute 0 in this case, it will be perfectly understandable. If you do want to emphasize the connection, you could write another scenario outline along the lines:

```
Given the volume has been set to <volume>
When action is triggered
Then the error message should be "Volume must be greater than 0 but is <volume>"
```

And then all your examples with nonpositive numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible as below:

Given the error message is `<error>` for `<volume>`:

```
Examples:
| volume    | error |
|  0        | Volume must be greater than 0 but is %1 |
```

In your `StepDef` file:

```
@Given("The error message is {string} for {string})
public void printError(String volume, String error) {
    error=error.replace("%1", error);
    System.out.println(error); // prints correctly with replacement
}
```